# What is the average number of collisions that will occur in a network using binary exponential backoff?

Tags: function, networking, communication, exponential

I'm writing a program to model the exponential backoff function used in Ethernet, but I'm not sure if my model is correct. Does anybody know the average number of collisions that will occur between N stations in a network, using these assumptions:

Assume the network has N stations. 
Each station has 1 frame to send and is only permitted to transmit at the beginning of a time slot. If two or more stations send at the beginning of a time slot, there will be a collision and each station must backoff, using the binary exponential backoff function described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff. Assume it takes one time slot for a frame to be transmitted; if a station sends out its frame with no collision, it remains inactive afterwards.

My program appears to have an average of N^2 total collisions for N stations, but I have not been able to find any source as to whether this is even close to correct. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: All N stations will try to transmit 1 frame at the first time slot?

Comment: @Cirdec Yes, that's right. So every station has a collision at the first time slot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an analytical solution for this. The N=2 case seems to have an analytical solution:

f(2) = sum{k=1;k=infinity}(k (2<sup>k</sup>-1)/2<sup>(k<sup>2</sup>+k)/2</sup>)

which comes out to about 1.64163, and the N=3 case isn't so simple.

When I simulate, I get this:

```
1: 0
2: 1.63772
3: 2.63643
4: 3.70488
5: 4.80432
6: 5.89181
7: 6.97669
8: 8.05497
9: 9.13575
10: 10.2013
11: 11.2844
12: 12.3304
13: 13.3865
14: 14.4362
15: 15.4775
16: 16.5293
17: 17.554
18: 18.6101
19: 19.6427
20: 20.6934
```

This looks more like N than N<sup>2</sup> to me.

Comment: How did you count the number of collisions? Number of points in time that a collision occurred, regardless of how many nodes were involved, or number of transmissions that collided?

Comment: @Cirdec: Number of collisions that occurred, regardless of how many transmissions were in them.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a simulation based on what's described in the wikipedia article. I don't see anywhere near N^2 collisions for N nodes, each attempting to send once at the first time frame, and never transmitting again once their single message is transmitted without collision.

```
Nodes   Coll    Lost    Succ    Frames  
0       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     
1       0.0     0.0     1.0     1.0     
2       1.655   3.31    2.0     5.334   
3       2.623   6.546   3.0     9.238   
4       3.764   10.698  4.0     14.327  
5       4.787   15.01   5.0     19.417  
6       5.944   19.869  6.0     25.821  
7       6.911   24.718  7.0     31.432  
8       8.033   30.155  8.0     38.464  
9       9.11    35.591  9.0     44.295  
10      10.165  41.137  10.0    51.748  
11      11.263  47.043  11.0    58.642  
12      12.395  53.029  12.0    66.874  
13      13.434  59.097  13.0    75.109  
14      14.449  65.097  14.0    81.917  
15      15.443  71.27   15.0    88.52   
16      16.453  77.544  16.0    97.961  
17      17.483  84.04   17.0    104.177 
18      18.711  90.877  18.0    116.288 
19      19.539  97.185  19.0    120.451 
20      20.67   104.059 20.0    130.952 
21      21.592  110.561 21.0    140.519 
22      22.691  117.556 22.0    146.973 
23      23.832  124.608 23.0    158.805 
24      24.667  131.162 24.0    163.776 
25      25.85   138.41  25.0    176.745 
26      26.92   145.641 26.0    189.071 
27      27.823  152.719 27.0    197.514 
28      28.942  160.104 28.0    207.642 
29      29.875  166.963 29.0    215.736 
30      30.866  174.161 30.0    225.025 
31      31.686  181.132 31.0    229.19  
32      32.947  189.118 32.0    242.804 
33      33.973  196.505 33.0    252.973 
34      34.948  203.764 34.0    263.166 
35      36.192  212.065 35.0    273.805 
36      36.795  218.552 36.0    277.656 
37      37.966  226.543 37.0    292.611 
38      39.197  234.595 38.0    307.013 
39      39.908  241.305 39.0    309.537 
40      41.057  249.609 40.0    323.217 
41      42.183  257.519 41.0    331.323 
42      43.223  265.094 42.0    344.867 
43      43.981  272.823 43.0    349.558 
44      44.934  280.297 44.0    355.776 
45      46.106  288.5   45.0    375.085 
46      47.277  296.807 46.0    384.67  
47      48.397  304.742 47.0    401.301 
48      49.207  312.141 48.0    412.576 
49      50.146  320.155 49.0    417.144
```

These are the average number of frames with a collision, the number of attempts to transmit that were involved in the collisions, the number of successful transmissions (which should be one per node), and the number of Frames it took for every node to transmit successfully.

Here's the simulation I put together in Haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, DeriveFunctor, OverlappingInstances #-}
-- OverlapingInstances shouldn't be required; there's no Functor instance for NodeDict.
module Main (
    main
) where

import System.Random
import qualified Data.Foldable as Foldable

main = do    
    output ["Nodes", "Coll", "Lost", "Succ", "Frames"]
    sequence_ $ map expirement $ take 50 $ iterate (1+) 0

expirement n = do
    let numTrials = 1000
    results <- sequence $ take numTrials $ repeat (trial n)
    let averages = summarize average results
    output [show n, show $ collisions averages, show $ lostTransmissions averages, show $ successfulTransmissions averages, show $ frames averages ]

trial n = do
    generator <- newStdGen
    let network = take n $ randomNodes generator
    let monitoredNetwork = (Passive $ Monitor [], network)
    let (Passive (Monitor result), _) = simulate monitoredNetwork
    return TrialResult {
        collisions = count collision result,
        lostTransmissions = sum $ map collided $ filter collision result,
        successfulTransmissions = count (==Frame) result,
        frames = length result
    }

-- Initialize network with exponential backoffs
randomNodes :: (RandomGen g) => g -> [Single (NodeDict Transmission Reception)]
randomNodes = map randomNode . splits
    where
        randomNode generator = Single $ backOffTransmissions (randomExponentialBackoffSchedules generator) $ transmit done

data TrialResult a = TrialResult {
    collisions :: !a,
    lostTransmissions :: !a,
    successfulTransmissions :: !a,
    frames :: !a
} deriving Show

average :: (Real r, Fractional a) => [r] -> a 
average results = (fromRational . toRational $ sum results) / (fromRational $ toRational $ length results)

summarize :: ([a] -> b) ->  [TrialResult a] -> TrialResult b
summarize summarizer results = TrialResult {
    collisions = summarizer $ map collisions results,
    lostTransmissions  = summarizer $ map lostTransmissions results,
    successfulTransmissions  = summarizer $ map successfulTransmissions results,
    frames = summarizer $ map frames results
}

output = putStrLn . concat . map (padr 8)       

padr :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
padr n s = take n $ s ++ repeat ' ' 

-- Model for nodes

class Transmitter t s where
    transmission :: s -> t

class Reciever r s where
    recieve :: r -> s -> s

-- Ordinary node with no type information attached
data NodeDict t r = NodeDict {
    _transmission :: t,
    _recieve :: r -> NodeDict t r
}

instance Transmitter t (NodeDict t r) where
    transmission = _transmission

instance Reciever r (NodeDict t r) where
    recieve = flip _recieve

-- Networks

class Transmitters t s where
    transmissions :: s -> [t]

-- Network consisting of a single node

newtype Single a = Single {
    only :: a
} deriving Functor

instance Transmitter t s => Transmitters t (Single s) where
    transmissions = (replicate 1) . transmission . only

-- Network instance for a list of networks

instance (Transmitters t s, Foldable.Foldable f) => Transmitters t (f s) where
    transmissions = Foldable.foldMap transmissions   

instance (Reciever r s, Functor f) => Reciever r (f s) where
    recieve r = fmap (recieve r)    

-- Network instances for tuples of networks

instance (Transmitters t sa, Transmitters t sb) => Transmitters t (sa, sb) where
    transmissions (a, b) = transmissions a ++ transmissions b

instance (Reciever r sa, Reciever r sb) => Reciever r (sa, sb) where
    recieve r (a, b) = (recieve r a, recieve r b)

-- Node that monitors the network

newtype Passive a = Passive {
    unPassive :: a
} deriving Functor

instance Transmitters t (Passive a) where
    transmissions _ = []

newtype Monitor a = Monitor {
    observations :: [a]
}

instance Reciever r (Monitor r) where
    recieve r s = Monitor (r:observations s)

-- Our signals

data Transmission = Done | Waiting | Transmitting deriving (Show, Eq)

data Reception = None | Frame | Collision {collided :: Int} deriving (Show, Eq)      

collision :: Reception -> Bool
collision (Collision _) = True
collision _ = False

-- Simulate collisions in a network

count :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count f = length . filter f

simulate :: (Transmitters Transmission s, Reciever Reception s) => s -> s
simulate state =
    case all (==Done) current of
        False ->
            simulate nextState
            where
                currentlyTransmitting = count (==Transmitting) current
                signal =
                    case currentlyTransmitting of
                        0 -> None
                        1 -> Frame
                        _ -> Collision currentlyTransmitting  
                nextState = recieve signal state
        _ -> state
    where current = transmissions state

-- Some network nodes
-- Node that does something, ignores what it recieves and does the next thing
node :: t -> NodeDict t r -> NodeDict t r
node t r = NodeDict {
    _transmission = t,
    _recieve = \_ -> r
}

-- Done forever
done :: NodeDict Transmission r
done = node Done done

-- Wait, then do the next thing
wait :: NodeDict Transmission r -> NodeDict Transmission r
wait = node Waiting

-- Transmit, then do the next thing
transmit :: NodeDict Transmission r -> NodeDict Transmission r
transmit = node Transmitting

-- When transmitting, check for collision and back off acording to the current schedule
backOffTransmissions :: [[Int]] -> NodeDict Transmission Reception -> NodeDict Transmission Reception
backOffTransmissions schedules n = NodeDict {
        _transmission = (transmission n),
        _recieve = case (transmission n==Transmitting) of
            True -> \r -> case (collision r) of
                True -> (iterate wait $ backOffTransmissions newSchedules n) !! steps
                    where
                        ((steps: thisSchedule) : remainingSchedules) = schedules
                        newSchedules = thisSchedule : remainingSchedules
                False -> backOffTransmissions (tail schedules) (recieve r n)
            _ -> \r -> backOffTransmissions schedules (recieve r n)
    }

-- Exponential backoff

powersOf2 :: Num n => [n]
powersOf2 = iterate (*2) 1

exponentialBackoffRanges :: Num n => [(n,n)]
exponentialBackoffRanges = map (\x -> (0, x-1)) $ tail powersOf2

exponentialBackoffGenerators :: (Num n, Random n, RandomGen g) => [g -> (n, g)]
exponentialBackoffGenerators = map randomR exponentialBackoffRanges

zipRandom :: RandomGen g => [g -> (a, g)] -> g -> [a]
zipRandom (step:steps) generator =
    let (value, nextGenerator) = step generator
    in value : zipRandom steps nextGenerator

splits :: RandomGen g =>  g -> [g]
splits = zipRandom (repeat split)

randomExponentialBackoffs :: (RandomGen g, Random n, Num n) => g -> [n]
randomExponentialBackoffs = zipRandom exponentialBackoffGenerators

randomExponentialBackoffSchedules :: (RandomGen g, Random n, Num n) => g -> [[n]]
randomExponentialBackoffSchedules = map randomExponentialBackoffs . splits
```

**Editted** to include more statistics to compare with other simulations